# Can I incorporate early stopping into a keras grid search?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, grid-search, hyperparameters

I'm performing a grid search on multiple hyperparameters and it will probably take a very long time.  There will probably be several combinations that are far from effective and if possible I would like to use early stopping when performing my grid search to prevent it from using the full 100 epochs on every combination of hyperparameters.  If a particular combination has not reduced the loss by a certain amount in the past 5 or 10 epochs I would like to stop testing that combination of hyperparameters and move on to the next candidate.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use earlystopping and add a delay to the trigger(patience). See documentation: https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping

Comment: I’ve used `earlyStopping` when fitting a model before but my question is how to use it when performing a grid search. I don’t want to stop the *entire* grid search process early when a hyper-parameter combination isn’t improving but I want to move onto the next combination of hyper-parameter candidates in the grid search @Denzel

Comment: When i was stuck in the same situation I just defined early stopping and passed it into model.fit. Well... i don't know other ways to do that.